# Vaadin Flow 24 - Select or Combox Custom Return Value?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm using Vaadin 24 - and would like to have a selectable list of items (either Select or Combobox Component) - that will allow a different display and return value.

For example - given this dataset:

```
ID  NAME
1   Joe
2   Sarah
3   Bill
4   Jennifer
```

I want the component to **display** the NAME, but **return** the ID.

In plain HTML I would do something like:

```
<select>
    <option name="person" value="1">Joe</option>
    <option name="person" value="2">Sarah</option>
    <option name="person" value="3">Bill</option>
    <option name="person" value="4">Jennifer</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way to do this in Vaadin?

Comment: Did you take a look at that official Docs? https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/combo-box

Comment: Hey @Knoobie! Nice to hear from you!  :)  Yes, I've looked at combobox and select documentation, searched for examples of setting the displayValue and returnValue to different things - with no luck.

Comment: If you open the very first example you can see two method calls. setItems to add all items / objects you need and setItemLabelGenerator to showcase a custom visual representation of the countries.

Comment: Holy crap, I'm stupid. I didn't let it register that setItemLabelGenerator and setItems were different.  SMH. Thanks, Knoobie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Koobie to the rescue - there are two methods for the comboBox:
`setItems()` which is the **return** value and
`setItemLabelGenerator()` which is the **display** item.

From the docs:

```
ComboBox<Country> comboBox = new ComboBox<>("Country");
comboBox.setItems(DataService.getCountries());
comboBox.setItemLabelGenerator(Country::getName);
add(comboBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the web components client-side, rather than the Flow framework, as the Java API of both components deals entirely in objects rather than specific values.

So, on the client-side, both the `vaadin-select` and `vaadin-combo-box` components work precisely as you describe: you give them a collection of JS objects through the `items` property, and specify which property in those objects is displayed as their labels (`item-label-path`) and which property is to be used as their values (`item-value-path`), as shown in the topmost TypeScript sample on [the Combo Box page](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/combo-box).

Comment: Thanks Rolf! Part of the reason my other team mates wanted to go with Vaadin - is their knowledge of CSS and HTML is **extremely** limited. So, for now, we're going to keep things on the server side. THANK YOU for your reply!